# Python add digits on either side of ' : ' ie. 22:11 + 22:22 = 44:33

Tags: python, string, time, int

```
22:11  +  22:22  =  44:33
varible_A = ('22:11')
varible_B = ('22:11')
```

the numbers on the left(22) are minutes
the numbers on the right(11) are seconds

I'm trying to add the two numbers to get

```
total = 44:22
```

This is a Bonus but would really help me out*

is it possible to treat the digits like time for instance...

```
varible_A = ('22:50')
varible_B = ('22:30')
```

I would like to get `45:20`

instead of

```
44:80
```

Comment: Please post any code that you've tried so far to solve this problem, and what problem you're having with it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`datetime.timedelta()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta) to model time durations:

```
from datetime import timedelta

def to_delta(value):
    minutes, seconds = map(int, value.split(':'))
    return timedelta(minutes=minutes, seconds=seconds)

var_a = to_delta('22:50')
var_b = to_delta('22:30')

var_a + var_b
```

You can then turn a `timedelta()` object back to a minutes + seconds representation:

```
def to_minutes_seconds(delta):
    return '{:02.0f}:{:02.0f}'.format(*divmod(delta.total_seconds(), 60))
```

Demo:

```
>>> var_a = to_delta('22:50')
>>> var_b = to_delta('22:30')
>>> var_a + var_b
datetime.timedelta(0, 2720)
>>> to_minutes_seconds(var_a + var_b)
'45:20'
```

Alternatively, the `str()` result of a `timedelta` is formatted as `HH:MM:SS`:

```
>>> str(var_a + var_b)
'00:45:20'
```

and may suit your needs too. Note that for deltas that present more than one hour, there is a difference between `str()` and `to_minutes_seconds()`; the former shows you hours, minutes and seconds, the latter just shows minutes, where the minutes value can be over 60. Deltas representing more than 24 hours gain an extra prefix for the number of days:

```
>>> str(timedelta(minutes=65, seconds=10))
'1:05:10'
>>> to_minutes_seconds(timedelta(minutes=65, seconds=10))
'65:10'
>>> str(timedelta(minutes=(60*24)+1, seconds=10))
'1 day, 0:01:10'
```

Comment: Use `return '{:.0f}:{:.0f}'.format(*divmod(delta.total_seconds(), 60))` in python 2.7

Comment: @TyrantWave: Indeed, that's the better option.

Comment: In most cases just `str(delta)` would suffice.

Comment: @thg435: It'll always include hours in that case. If you want to display *only* a minute count, then that would not work. Expanded to give some examples and cover the difference.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: it's unclear to me either what result the OP expects from `45:00 + 20:00`.

Comment: @thg435: Well, now the OP has both options.

Comment: That works, now I'am trying to add similar numbers but that are stored in a list  ie..  timelist = ['11:22','22:33','44:55']

Comment: Call `to_delta()` *per element* in the list then.

Comment: Sum them all to a `timedelta()` total with `sum((to_delta(item) for item in timelist), timedelta())`.

Answer (score 2):

I think these should be represented by objects, rather than one line comprehensions etc... As such my suggestion is to use a class like follows:

```
class Time(object):
    def __init__(self,minutes,seconds):
        self.minutes = minutes
        self.seconds = seconds
    def __add__(self,other):
        return Time(self.minutes+other.minutes,self.seconds+other.seconds)
    def __str__(self):
        return "{0}:{1}".format(self.minutes,self.seconds)

A = Time(22,11)
B = Time(22,22)
print(A+B)
```

Produces

```
>>> 
44:33
```

Comment: Now add `22:50` and `22:30` :-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters I see your point, but the OP doesn't seem to be averse to such behavior.

Answer (score 2):

You can Use similar function

```
def add_with_column(*args):
    res = (0,0)
    for data in args:
        nums = map(int, data.split(':'))
        res = [i + j for i,j in zip(res, nums)]
    return ':'.join([str(res[0] + res[1]/60), str(res[1] % 60)])

>>> add_with_column('22:50', '22:30')
'45:20'
```

Comment: Thanks, what if the numbers were stored like varible_list = ['21:12','34:32']

Comment: don't know what is expected. Maybe just replace ':' with '.'

Comment: no i mean if I had a list of times and i needed to add them all together

Comment: add_with_column(*timelist) or You can check whether args[0] is Iterable and run cycle for it if it is

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
>>> def add_time(t1,t2):
    h1,s1 = map(int,t1.split(":"))
    h2,s2 = map(int,t2.split(":"))
    q,r = divmod(s1+s2, 60)
    return "{0}:{1:02d}".format( h1+h2+q, r)
... 
>>> add_time('22:30','22:50')
'45:20'
>>> add_time('22:30','22:30')
'45:00'
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to do this without importing any external machinery would be:

```
def add(time1,time2):
    t1 = map(int,time1.split(':')) # t1[0] is minutes, t1[1] is seconds
    t2 = map(int,time2.split(':')) # map will apply int() to both elements of the array
    m = t1[0]+t2[0]+(t1[1]+t2[1])/60 # New minutes; recall that 70/60=1 for integer division
    s = (t1[1]+t2[1]) % 60 #new seconds
    return str(m)+":"+str(s)
add('22:30','22:50') # prints '45:20'
```

Of course, you can always import from datetime (which is probably better for practical applications), but if you want to implement time operations by yourself, this is how you can do so.

Answer (score 1):

```
a = '22:50'
b = '22:30'

def add_time(a, b):
    a = map(int, a.split(':'))
    b = map(int, b.split(':'))
    a[1] += b[1]
    a[0] += b[0] + a[1]//60
    a[1] %= 60
    return '{}:{}'.format(*a)

print a, b, add_time(a,b)
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to split the times into their components

```
def split_time(time):
    return time.split(':')
```

and add them

```
def add_times(time1, time2):
    minutes = time1[0] + time2[0]
    seconds = time1[1] + time2[1]
    return minutes, seconds
```

and do modular arithmetic to "carry the minute" when appropriate

```
def carry_the_minute(minutes, seconds):
    minutes += seconds / 60
    seconds %= 60
    return minutes, seconds
```

and create a representation of the result

```
def represent_time(minutes, seconds):
    """Specifies two-character-wide seconds with leading 0."""
    return "{0}:{1:02d}".format(minutes, seconds)
```

---

Putting it all together will look something like this:

```
def add_times(time1, time2):
    time1 = split_time(time1)
    time2 = split_time(time2)
    minutes, seconds = add_times(time1, time2)
    minutes, seconds = carry_the_minute(minutes, seconds)
    print represent_time(minutes, seconds)
```